# raise a NOTE exception during R CMD check

Tags: r, cran, r-package

Is there any way I could raise my own NOTE exception from within the unit tests in the *checking tests ...* step of `R CMD check`?
In general I would like to have a NOTE in `00check.log` if database was not available during unit tests.
Dirty solutions welcome.

Update: Actually I see much more use cases for such feature, adding bounty.

Comment: I am not sure you can--you'd need access to the `Log` object in the environment of the `tools` package.

Comment: If you're using testthat, you can use `print` inside of a testing file. It's not a NOTE, but at least its some output you could check for that isn't going to make the check fail.

Comment: You might consider including your own questions before submission with `devtools::release()`. From the help file: "You can also add arbitrary extra questions by defining an (un-exported) function called release_questions() that returns a character vector of additional questions to ask"

Answer (score 1):

Generally tests are run in a separate process.  The `Log` object that Dirk referred to is a local variable in the original process, so there's no way to access it.

Errors in the child process are detected by a non-zero return value.  Other anomalies in the test script aren't seen unless you've saved a copy of the desired output; then the comparison of new output with old would see them.